# Possible to get the code powering a view in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Well I'm a bit of an idiot, I wrote a view then accidently closed the window so now I don't have a copy of the query powering it.  Syntax was:

```
 CREATE VIEW view_name AS SELECT something FROM somewhere
```

Is there a way to get the "SELECT something FROM somewhere" or am I going to have to rewrite it from memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SHOW CREATE VIEW view_name;
```